# .NET MAUI android app is crashing in release mode

Tags: c#, android, maui, proguard

I have tested my android app in debug mode on android devices it's working fine but it is crashing in release mode. It is giving me the following error in the Device Log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Landroidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences$PrefKeyEncryptionScheme;" field "AES256_SIV" in class "Landroidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences$PrefKeyEncryptionScheme;" or its superclasses
```

I have tried to make change in proguard.cfg as it is suggested in the following [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13413)

```
-keep class android.support.v4.widget.Space { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v4.widget.Space
-keepmembers public class androidx.security.crypto.** {
    public <fields>;
}
```

But still it is not working. I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions?

Comment: It is recommended that you can create a new thread on the GitHub issue first. Then you can try to update the AndroidX Security library to the latest version and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I have taken to resolve this error are:

1. Creating a `proguard.cfg` file in "Project/Platforms/Android/" in your file system.
2. In your .csproj file, set it as a `ProguardConfiguration`:

```xml
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
    <ProguardConfiguration Include="Platforms\Android\proguard.cfg" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

3. In your `proguard.cfg` file, add the following lines (you may be able to use less broad rules like in your original post but I have not tested this):

```
-keep class androidx.security.crypto.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.crypto.tink.** { *; }
```

4. Configure selective backup for MAUI essentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#selective-backup

- You will also want to setup data extraction rules for use on Android 12+. App center has a good example of how those should look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#52-for-android-12-api-level-31-or-higher