# .NET MAUI raises an error in Android related to AES256_SIV

Tags: c#, android, maui

I deployed my `.NET8` `MAUI` in the Google Play and their tests raise this error

> Java.Lang.Error: no "Landroidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences$PrefKeyEncryptionScheme;" field "AES256_SIV" in class "Landroidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences$PrefKeyEncryptionScheme;" or its superclases

I'm not sure what this error means. Checking the call stack, I think this is related to a piece of code where I read the `SecureStorage`.

```
string userId = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("userId") ?? "";
```

If so, what is this error about? How can I fix it? Is there any missing configuration?

Comment: Take a look at that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317088/net-maui-android-app-is-crashing-in-release-mode